# Label.Text last char in string gets moved to front of string, why?

Tags: c#, text, label, axis-labels

I have a c# program with several forms and labels. Some of these labels are acting weird, the last char in the .Text Property shows up in the beginning of the char.

For Example:
In the property viewer for my label the 
Text property is "Mode:" 
but in the designer form and when i run the program it shows up as ":Mode"

Also in another example
I have a chart control where of the axis titles  is "Time (Hrs:Min:Sec)" 
however it shows up as ")Time (Hrs:Min:Sec" when the program is executed.

Any Idea of what could be happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what to show as I set this part up in the designer,
Do you want designer code?

Comment: Please don't prefix  your question titles with "C#". On [so], we use tags to categorize questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have inadvertently changed the value of the labels' RightToLeft (Windows forms) or FlowDirection (WPF) properties.

Comment: Yes! Simple solution, Thanks for the help!